# StackAd Wordpress Plugin - Display Community Ads on Your WordPress Blog with Minimal Effort

Tags: app, php, wordpress, blog

### Screenshot

[image]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.org](https://s.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stackad/screenshot-1.png?r=503430))</sub>

### About

Now you can easily display community based advertisements (like [these](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1089/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011)) on your WordPress blog with almost no effort. The plugin ships with a widget you can add to the sidebar - in fact, you can even run multiple instances of the plugin if you want.

All Stack Exchange sites with a Meta are supported and the data is cached for 6 hours in case you are worried about the performance hit this plugin might have on your blog.

#### License

[GPL version 2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html).

#### Download

You can download the plugin from here:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stackad/

...**or** you can simply open up your WordPress dashboard and search for 'stackad' in the plugin installation page.

#### Platform

Officially supported on WordPress 3.3+ but I don't see why it wouldn't work with older versions.

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

Written in PHP and JavaScript.

The code is available online at:
https://github.com/nathan-osman/StackAd-WordPress-Plugin

Comment: **Note:** you can see the plugin in action here: http://2buntu.com